# Expect ssh script (execute command on remote machine)

Tags: ssh, expect

I'm writing an expect script that executes a command on a remote server using ssh.

Command syntax: `ssh <classname> <command>`

Code:

```
set ip "hive28.cs.berkeley.edu"
set class [lindex $argv 0]
// set $user and $ip according to class

set cmd [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh "$user\@$ip '$cmd'"
expect "assword"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
~/foo> ssh2 162 'pwd'

spawn ssh ***@hive28.cs.berkeley.edu 'pwd'
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hive28.cs.berkeley.edu 'pwd': Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$password\r""
    invoked from within <...>
```

But when I run the generated command directly, it works (ignore the `gdircolors` warnings):

```
~/foo> ssh ***@hive28.cs.berkeley.edu 'pwd'
***@hive28.cs.berkeley.edu's password: 
/home/ff/cs162/adm/bashrc.d/70-gnu.sh: line 36: gdircolors: command not found
/home/cc/cs162/sp16/class/***
```

Comment: If you `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` first, you don't need expect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
set ip "hive28.cs.berkeley.edu"
set class [lindex $argv 0]

set cmd [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh "$user@$ip" "$cmd"
expect "assword"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

The problem seems to be with your quoting. `"$user\@$ip"` and `"$cmd"` are two separate arguments.

Comment: 2 minor points about Tcl(expect): 1. `@` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped; 2. Tcl does not require quotes around variables, even if the variable value contains whitespace.

Comment: I'm fully aware; I was trying to make minimal changes to OP's script. Quotes are for clarity; they don't cause harm. But, good to point out in a comment! I'll remove the `@` escape even though it was in the original code. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help :)